# Add a dynamically created route to Angular routing

Tags: angular

How can I add a dynamically changing route to my Angular routes? The reason for wanting to do this is that a logged-in user gets logged out when the path changes to the dynamically created URL.

**The process:**

As part of the checkout process, a 3rd party payment service reroutes to a dynamically created path (still part of the same domain), and once the payment resolves, it is routed to a payment success page. But during this routing changes, the user gets logged out. How can I deal with this behavior to keep the user logged in?

I was wondering if one could create a route that doesn't look at the dynamic part of the URL. Something like this, adding a `*` after the route URI:

```
{ path: 'payment-status*', component: PaymentStatusComponent },
```

**Below are my route changes:**

**Start URL:**

```
https://mySiteUrl.co.za/payment-details
```

**Rerouted Dynamic URL:**

```
https://mySiteUrl.co.za/payment-status?id=49B23D5DB1288B7ECFBC795C1.uat01-vm-tx01&resourcePath=%2Fv1%2Fcheckouts%2F49B23D5DB12856CFBC795C1.uat01-vm-tx01%2Fpayment
```

**Destination URL:**

```
https://mySiteUrl.co.za/order-done
```

Thanks in advance!